# Function statement vs function expression weird behaviour

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = function b() {

};

console.log(typeof b); //gives undefined
console.log(typeof a); //gives function
```

Why the difference in the two outputs?

I understand the difference between function expression and function statement, but not able to understand the output above.

From what I know, javascript makes `var a` point to the memory allocated to named function b here. In such a case `typeof b` should also return `function` but it returns `undefined`

Any explanations?

Comment: See https://kangax.github.io/nfe/.

Answer (score 6):

Because the name of a named function expression is scoped to the expression.

```js
var a = function b() {
    console.log(typeof b); //gives function
    console.log(typeof a); //gives function
};

console.log(typeof b); //gives undefined
console.log(typeof a); //gives function

a();
```

Comment: To be 100% precise, there are two scopes involved. The first is the scope of the entire function expression; the second is that between the curly brackets. The scope of the name is the former. In other words, the following is valid, if useless: `a = function b(arg = b) { };`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the difference in the two outputs?

You're taking a function expression for a function named `b` and assigning it to a variable named `a`. That means `a` is in scope where the expression occurs, but `b` is not; it's only in scope within the function. (The whole function, including the parameter list; that last part is only relevant for ES2015+, not ES5 and earlier: You can use `b` as the value of a default parameter.)

You probably expected `b` to be in scope where the expression was, because that's true for a function *declaration*:

```js
function b() {
}
console.log(typeof b);
```

But this is just a difference in how function declarations and function expressions are handled.

Comment: *it's only in scope within the function* How do you define "within" here?

Comment: I would say *within* means *between the curly braces after `function`*

Comment: @gyre: Not just the body, the parameter list as well. The entire function.

Comment: Of course, assuming that we are speaking ES6. Not sure that was OP's intention but I know what you mean.

Comment: @gyre: :-) Probably not. But it's what torazaburo was getting at above.

Answer (score -1):

With

```
function b(){

}
```

you declare a function called `b`. This statement has *no return value* and therefor the return value is undefined.

To declare an anonymous function you have to omit the function name in the declaration, like this:

```
function(){

};
```

This one is just a function *literal* you can assign to a variable like that:

```
var a = function(){

};
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.